# .htacces rewrite do not gives $_Get

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to redirect my pages from:

http://domain.com/collections/life/

to ./collection.php?coll=life

the .htacces-file shoud be placed in http://domain.com/collections and if the REQUEST_FILENAME is not present it shout redirect.

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /collection.php?coll=$1 [L]
```

The redirect works but var_dump($_GET) in my collection.php gives:

```
array(1) { ["coll"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Whats wrong to give the correct $_Get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're not capturing `$1` on LHS pattern. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) /collection.php?coll=$1 [L,QSA]
```